# Trying to convert a column with strings to float via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have looked but on stackoverflow and not found a solution for my problem. Any help highly appeciated.

After importing a csv I noticed that all the types of the columns are object and not float.

My goal is to convert all the columns but the YEAR column to float. I have read that you first have to strip the columns for taking blanks out and then also convert NaNs to 0 and then try to convert strings to floats. But in the code below I'm getting an error.

[image: Table of data]

My code in Jupyter notes is:

[image: Code]

And I get the following error.

[image: Error message]

How do I have to change the code.

All the columns but the YEAR column have to be set to float.

If you can help me set the column Year to datetime that would be also very nice. But my main problem is getting the data right so I can start making calculations.

Thanks

Runy

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be

```
df = df.astype(float)
df['YEAR'] = df['YEAR'].astype(int)
```

Also, your code fails because you have two columns with the same name `BBPWN`, so when you do `df['BBPWN']`, you will get a dataframe with those two columns. Then, `df['BBPWN'].str` will fail.